# Autodesk Forge API. How to get specific version of item?

Tags: api, autodesk-forge

I'm to get a specific version of the item from the Autodesk Forge. I use this [instruction](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-item-GET/) to do it. There is a template of a request:

```
GET projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/item
```

So my request look similar (I cuted out a part for brevity):

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/a.cGV ... TU2/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.lTvo5GGBRzidiQ8Kredbaw?version=1/item
```

But the request returns **error 400** (Bad request).

When I just get the itemin the same way (using an intended for this [template](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/) of course) all is okay.

Should I to use [this](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-item-GET/) template or other?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `version_id` should be escaped into a URL safe form since there are some reserved and unsafe keywords ( i.e. `:`, `.`, `?` and `=` ) in this parameter. They will invalid your request to the Forge service. ([Ref](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt))

For example, your version_id is `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.d34fdsg3g?version=2`, then you have to tranform it like:

`urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D2`.

In JavaScript, the `encodeURIComponent()`([Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) function can help you do this transformation. Here is a sample for you:

`encodeURIComponent('urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.d34fdsg3g?version=2')`

If your codes are written in C#, you can call `Uri.EscapeDataString()` ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)) to archive the same goal.